# Reading from a file online c++

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("www.a.com", "http");
    if(!s)
        std::cout << "Could not connect to www.a.com\n";
    s  << "GET /b.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n"
       << "Host: www.a.com\r\n"
       << "Accept: */*\r\n"
       << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n" ;
    for(std::string line; getline(s, line); )
         std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

of course  i use a proper website instead of "a.com" 
But i always get the "Could not connect to www.a.com" 
Any idea why?

Comment: What does `s.error().message()` say?

Comment: Could not connect to www.a.com
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 16:15:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: What if you use a _valid_ address?

Comment: Please post the url you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get your request formatted correctly. For google:

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("www.google.com", "http");
    if(!s)
        std::cout << "Could not connect to www.a.com\n";
    s  << "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
        << "Host: www.google.com\r\n"
        << "User-Agent: Boost\r\n"
        << "Accept: */*\r\n"
        << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n" ;
    for(std::string line; getline(s, line); )
        std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Note, there is no colon after the `GET`. The `/` is the root path to just about any website. Did you also set your `Host:` ?

The above code gets me a 200 OK from google.

Comment: "works on my machine" usually not the best answer.. also, it seems that OP is getting stuck in the first `if (!s)` - he doesn't get to the `s <<..` code.

Comment: Hi, @Default, in his comment he says he is getting a: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Ok @Default, if it is his message, I'm baffled and will delete my answer. He should show the url he is trying to connect to.

Comment: I agree with you. I voted to close the question for that reason. There's too little information for a proper response. (The fact that he's not using any brackets seems to me that the code may not be complete either.) Keep or delete your answer is up to you. I was just noting that the fact that it works on your machine will probably not help the OP.

Comment: I couldn't post the url for security reasons since the website is still under construction, anyways thanks @lakeweb for the answer it worked now. Sorry I can't accept since i'm new to the community and i don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Ok Lui, glad it works for you now. Thanks for the check.